# Class with other classes in composition c++

Tags: c++, class

Hello guys I have a class car with another class inside (driver) which has another class inside (drivingLicense) how is the correct way to construct the classes, now I am doing this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Driver {
public:
    string name;
    driverLicense* license;
    int age;
    Driver(string name, string adress, int experience)
    {
        setName(name);
        this->license->setName(name);
        this->license->setAdress(adress);
        this->license->setExperience(experience);
    }
    void setName(string name)
    {
        this->name = name;
    }
    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
};
class driverLicense {
public:
    string name;
    string adress;
    int experience;
    driverLicense(string name, string adress, int experience)
    {
        setName(name);
        setAdress(adress);
        setExperience(experience);
    }
    void setName(string name)
    {
        this->name = name;
    }
    void setExperience(int experience)
    {
        this->experience = experience;
    }
    void setAdress(string adress)
    {
        this->adress = adress;
    }
    string getName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }
    string getAdress()
    {
        return this->adress;
    }
    int getExperience()
    {
        return this->experience;
    }
};
class Car {
public:
    int age;
    Driver* driver;
    Car(int age, string driverName, string driverAdress, int driverExperience)
    {
        this->age = age;
        this->driver->setName(driverName);
        this->driver->license->setName(driverName);
        this->driver->license->setAdress(driverAdress);
        this->driver->license->setExperience(driverExperience);
    }
    int getAge()
    {
        return this->age;
    }
    Driver* getDriver()
    {
        return this->driver;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Car car(7, "Matei", "Europa", 2);
    cout << "Driver name: " << car.getDriver()->license->getName() << endl;
    cout << "Driver adress: " << car.getDriver()->license->getAdress() << endl;
    cout << "Driving experience: " << car.getDriver()->license->getExperience() << endl;
}
```

When I build the program I get no errors but when I run the program the console exits with code **-1073741819**.
Please help me!

Comment: where do u instantiate Driver and driverLicense?

Comment: @solti I am sorry but I don't understand what do you mean?

Comment: This program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an uninitialized variable `driver` in `Car`'s constructor.

Comment: Tip: When you see an insane number like -1073741819, pop it into your search engine of choice and see if the program is trying to tell you something. If you don't get any meaningful hits, convert it into hex, C0000005 in this case, and search for that as well. -1073741819 is the error code for Access Violation. The program tried to read or write something that it doesn't own.

Comment: Unrelated: read up on the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and it's friends as it is likely to be the cause of your next question.

Comment: In addition, familiarize yourself with the use the the debugging utility that came with your development tools. A debugger allows you to run a program at your speed and let you see what the program does as it does it. When you catch the program doing something you didn't expect, Bam! There's your bug. The next part's a bit trickier: Figuring out what you should have done instead.

Comment: When using the debugger I get **Exception thrown: read access violation.
this was nullptr.** But I can't figure out how to fix the problem.

Comment: In class Car there is `Driver* driver`. You should do something like  `driver = new Driver(name, adress, experience` otherwise since it is not initialized to any thing it will be `nullptr`. This is what I meant by class instantiation. Read on class instantiation in c++. You should do similar with driver `driverLicense = new driverLicense (...`